# How to decode celery result from the Mongo DB?

Tags: python, celery, pymongo

When I execute the task using celery where backend is Mongo DB, It is storing the result in the form of `BinData(0,"gAJLEy4=")` in the database.

How can we read this 'result' data from the Mongo DB and decode it to string?

I want to write a new python script where it reads all the results from the Mongo db.

Is there any direct API available in the celery result module or in pymongo to process this result?

In my case the result will be the HTML source of web pages (i.e crawled data)

Answer (score 5):

Got an answer. By default, Celery is storing the result as a pickle object in the data store.
We can retrive this value by calling a function pickle.loads

```
import pickle
# Connect db
# Fetch record from the collection
str_result = pickle.loads(c['result'])
```